# What goes in the fileParts argument of the file constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, backend, file-handling

I'm making a web application with flask, and I've stored an access token as a text file. I want to then read the content of the file from a javascript function. However, the function i saw on [This site](https://javascript.info/file) tells me that I need some sort of argument named `fileParts`, which it describes as "an array of Blob/BufferSource/String values." What does this mean, and what should I put in there?

Javascript:

```js
    function getAccessToken() {
        let file = new File("../../data/Authorisation.txt")
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        var result = reader.result;

        return result.substring(14);
    }
```

Error message:
"Uncaught TypeError: File constructor: At least 2 arguments required, but only 1 passed"

Comment: Better documentation is in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File). It's the contents of the file if you're not getting it from a `FileReader`.

Comment: Note that you can't specify the filename to read in JavaScript. It has to be selected by the user using `<input type="file">`. This is a security feature to prevent websites from reading arbitrary files on the user's system.

Comment: So if I'm not writing to the file, is it fine to put an array with an empty string: `[""]` or will that delete my file

Comment: wait what would the issue be with reading arbitrary files? and would cookies be an alternative to look into?

Comment: If you have a file containing your personal finances, do you really want any website to get a copy of it?

Comment: You don't usually use `new File` directly. You get the file from the `<input>`.

Comment: oh okay that makes sense